# How is the loopback device implemented?

Tags: networking, kernel, interface, routing

[The loopback networking interface](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1911/what-is-the-loopback-interface)

> is a virtual network device implemented entirely in software.

**But how is this implementation actually accomplished and how do you manipulate it?**

As far as I know, IPs are marked as local in the local routing table:

```
ip route show table local
```

Sending to an IP marked as local will trigger the loopback device.  **But is this detection done by purely by routing tables or also by some other kernel operations?**

Edit: My ultimate goal is to manipulate the loop-device configuration, so that sending datagrams among my interfaces (two wlan adapters) on my laptop will result in real traffic / datagrams in the network and not in local loops.
    Interface 1 -> WLAN -> Interface 2 and NOT: Interface 1 -> LOOP -> Interface 2

Answer (score 8):

It's entirely handled through the routing tables.

It's pretty easy to try out in a virtual machine, if you want to have fun. I don't take responsibility for anything that might happen on the machine where you try this.

First let's change the netmask of `lo` to 255.255.0.0:

```
sudo ip addr del 127.0.0.1/8 dev lo; sudo ip addr add 127.0.0.1/16 dev lo
```

Now let's look at our `lo`:

```
$ ip -4 addr show dev lo
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 16436 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN 
    inet 127.0.0.1/16 scope host lo
```

Where would packets to 127.1.1.1 go?

```
$ sudo ip route get 127.1.1.1
127.1.1.1 via 172.16.22.2 dev eth0  src 172.16.22.130 
    cache  mtu 1500 advmss 1460 hoplimit 64
```

We start pinging in another terminal:

```
$ ping 127.1.1.1
```

Let's monitor ICMP traffic on eth0:

```
$ sudo tcpdump -i eth0 icmp
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on lo, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 65535 bytes
07:28:42.060077 IP 172.16.22.130 > 127.1.1.1: ICMP echo request, id 5665, seq 4, length 64
07:28:43.059920 IP 172.16.22.130 > 127.1.1.1: ICMP echo request, id 5665, seq 5, length 64
```

I'll leave you with the exercise of changing the netmask of `lo` on a remote machine to 255.255.0.0 and adding the IP address 127.1.1.1 to their network interface. You can see ICMP replies coming back. Note that routers might not play nicely.